# How to inspect HTTP requests in Safari 8 or later

Tags: safari

I can't seem to find a way to view the raw HTTP requests sent by safari to the webserver. Does anyone know how you can do this in Safari 8.

I did manage to find some HTTP headers in the resource tab of the web inspector [image] But I want to see the raw (in plain text) HTTP request

Answer (score 56):

Actually, there is a way to do that, just like Chrome:

On the Inspector window, at the Resource sidebar (at right), there's a small arrow at the "**Request Data**" subsection. That's where we need to click!

[image]

(Sorry for the browser language in Portuguese, btw).

Once the data screen is loaded, you can even switch between **Request** and **Response** views.

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Which version of Safari is this?

Comment: latest version: 10.0.2

Comment: This looks promising but I can't found that gray arrow button. Safari 10.0.3

Comment: jesus christ, cheerios :)

Comment: Oh I accidentally found myself back here, the gray arrow button now located beside the request name, in the screenshot above, it's on where the spinning loading bar icon located. You need to hover on top of the requests row to show the button.

Comment: Note that this is under the SOURCES tab and not the Network one ‍♂️

Comment: if you don't see Down Arrow icon to change between Request and Response, expand developer tools window.

Comment: Does this work for https?   It seems it doesn't, for me.  Can it be made to work?

In the pull-down, I only see "Response" and "Response (DOM tree)", not "Request".  

It still works on a site that supports only plain http. I can use @enyo's method, or these.     In Safari 14.   Then I see "Response", "Response (DOM tree)", AND "Request" in the pull-down.  And on the Sizes tab, under Body, I see the body size and an arrow, instead of just a dash.

Answer (score 25):

The only solution I found, was to use the Timeline and select "Network Requests" on the left.
Click the red "Record" icon, so that you record all your requests. They will then appear in the timeline viewer. Then make sure that you select this time span (scrolling inside the timeline shows a smaller or bigger time span), an the request will appear below the timeline viewer.

[image: Timeline viewer in Safari]

Comment: A record button! Who knew that silly red dot below the resources button did anything... Thanks!

Comment: Speaking on terrible UI, you guys noticed the “X” at the right of “Network Requests”? Can anyone guess for what is that for?

Comment: @HenryMazza Looks like it just removes it from the graph view. This way if you don't want Network Requests clogging up the other information you can get rid of it. Instruments has a similar UI.

Comment: This is so hard to use. It appears that certain AJAX requests simply don't appear, even though they definitely happened while recording. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 8):

For later versions of Safari, you can right click on the row in the network tab, (in the white section on the right, not the gray section on the left) and "Copy as cURL". Then paste that into a text editor and look at the bottom where it specifies "--data".

Answer (score 7):

In Safari 12, select the row in the network tab. The response will be displayed in the main area. Above it will be a few tabs. Select the Headers tab and take a look in the request part of the displayed data for some request info. For details on the request data, take a look under "Request Data". If applicable, there will be a small arrow there that you can press to see the full content of the request.

Answer (score 5):

Solution - Safari version v14.0.x

> Network > Headers tab - and then by clicking on a **SMALL ARROW** that displayed the entire payload on a new tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Safari timeline is not so informative as Chrome one. The latter shows all delays separately: DNS, connect, blocking, transferring and so on. It lets you can easily see what to optimize first.